# present perfect, past simple, present perfect continues

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I cannot understand these.

1st

- We **didn't** win our first four games, but now we are second in the league.  (o)
- We **haven't** win our first four games, but now we are second in the league. (x)

2nd

- For the last half hour I **have been watching** some dolphins near the boat, and I feel really happy to be here. (o)
- For the last half hour I **have watched** some dolphins near the boat, and I feel really happy to be here. (x)

Why each first line is correct?

Comment: But the second line of 2nd is correct.

Comment: @user405662 Acceptable, maybe, but the continuous tense is much more idiomatic in this context.

Comment: I agree with you, Kate Bunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) It should be **haven't won**, but this would only be said *after* those four games and *before* any more have been played. "Now we are second in the league" implies that the team have won plenty of games since those four losing ones. **Didn't win** is used because the losing games were some time in the past.

(2) Similarly, the half hour of dolphin-watching is in the immediate past (and may still be continuing!).